# Using nested apex:repeat and pageBlockTable in a page

Tags: visualforce, map, repeat, table

Well, I couldn't find a way to explain in a simple way my issue (thus the poor title).

I am trying to build a page in which I have to separate some records using two fields on it. One of them is a date, an the other is a relationship. First, I would like to build different tables for each date, and then, on those, I would like to list them by result.

This object, however, can have multiple records for the same line in the table, so I would like to create more columns using apex:repeat.

The logic would be to create a map:

```
Map<Date, Map<Id, List<CustomObject__c>>>
```

and then iterate over the date using `apex:repeat`, then over the Id.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myMap}" var="data">
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!myMap[data]}" var="emp" id="tableProgramacoes">
        <apex:repeat value="{!myMap[data][emp]}" var="prog">
            <apex:outputText value="{!prog.Field__c}"/>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:repeat>
```

For what I understand, this would be similar to iterating 3 collections, like:

```
for (Date data : map.keySet())
{
    for (Id emp : map.get(data).keySet())
    {
        for (CustomObject__c co : map.get(data).get(emp))
        {
            System.debug(co.Field__c);
        }
    }
}
```

Or this is what I think would work, because even if this compiles, when accessing the page, Salesforce raises an error in the expression of the inner repeater. Is there a way to make this iteration work?

Edit:

Changed code. Still getting errors.
Also thanks Adrian for the nice title!

Comment: you have really asked two separate questions here, the way I see it. I answered your OP, which opened up a separate question. You should roll back your OP and ask a separate question, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had trouble making this work with `pageBlockTable` (or `dataTable`) but I could with `apex:repeat`

Using this controller property with unimaginative accountNames:

```
public map<Date,List<Account>> dateToAccountsMap {
  get {return new map<Date,List<Account>> {   
    Date.newInstance(2020,1,1) => new List<Account> {new Account(name = 'Account2020-00'),
                                                     new Account(name = 'Account2020-01')},
    Date.newInstance(2021,1,1) => new List<Account> {new Account(name = 'Account2021-00'),
                                                     new Account(name = 'Account2021-01')}

    };
  } 
  private set;
}
```

and this VF:

```
<apex:page controller="FooController" >

     <apex:repeat  value="{!dateToAccountsMap}" var="dateKey"> <!-- outer -->            
         <apex:outputText value="{!dateKey}"/>
         <table>
         <apex:repeat value="{!dateToAccountsMap[dateKey]}" var="a"> <!-- inner -->
             <tr><td><apex:outputText value="{!a.name}"/></td></tr>
         </apex:repeat>    
         </table>
     </apex:repeat>
 </apex:page>
```

I rendered (add your own css styling for the HTML table):

```
Wed Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2020
  Account2020-00
  Account2020-01
Fri Jan 01 00:00:00 GMT 2021
  Account2021-00
  Account2021-01
```

Comment: Sounds like my hunch about `pageBlockTable` may have been correct after all.

Comment: @AdrianLarson.  Yeah,  I couldn't get pageBlocktable to iterate over a map 'get' that returned a list.  No doubt sfdcfox or Keith C knows how to do this :-)

Comment: It seems that Salesforce might have some limitations with pageBlockTable or dataTable. I redid my code to use only repeats, and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Your `prog` variable is actually a *record*, not an *index*. It represents `co` in your `Apex` parallel.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!myMap[data][emp]}" var="co">
    <apex:outputText value="{!co.Field__c}" />
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: I bet you are right, but after changing things in my code, I get a new error: "Map key null not found in map". I already checked my code for null values, even throwing an exception for this case. Any ideas?

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Do you still get the error if you comment out the innermost `repeat`?

Comment: No. The issue is with the inner repeat, I believe. If I comment it, then the page loads successfully.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira And if you run that `Apex`, none of the `emp` values are `null`?

Comment: Precisely. There are no null values. I even ran a query in the db just to make sure of that.

Comment: What happens if you just comment out the `outputText` @RenatoOliveira? Or if you change the `pageBlockTable` to another `repeat`?

Comment: The same error occurs.

Comment: @RenatoOliveira Guess you didn't try switching `pageBlockTable` to `repeat` after all?

Comment: I didn't. I assumed the error is within the pageBlockTable internal code, since I can use the repeat tag and it works. And I currently don't have the time to look further into this, so I took this approach, even if I have to create a custom CSS for a table.